# How to relate Abpuser Table to other tables ABP Webframework

Tags: abp

I have a requirement. There are 3 types of users

- Social User
- Influencer
- Business User

These three users need to be linked to same AbpUser Table. Something like. One AbpUser has one to one relationship with Social, Influencer and Business user. Right now I am not able to make the Social user having reference to Abpuser. same with other user types.

I have the Following classes,

```
public class SocialUser : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public Guid AppUserId { get; set; }// Foreign key referenceing the Appuser 

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    // Other code block removed for clarity

}
```

And Appuser Table like this,

```
public class AppUser : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IUser
{
    
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

  // ..... Other code block removed for clarity.
}

builder.Entity<AppUser>(u =>
        {
            u.ToTable(AbpIdentityDbProperties.DbTablePrefix + "Users"); //Sharing the same table "AbpUsers" with the IdentityUser
            u.ConfigureByConvention();

            u.ConfigureAbpUser();
            u.HasOne<SocialUser>().WithOne().HasForeignKey<SocialUser>(x => x.AppUserId).IsRequired();
            });
            // Other code blocks removed for clarity
        }
```

But while running the Migrations, the AppSocialUser **doesn't have foreign key constraint referring to AppUser**.

Any ideas, Please let me know. Your valuable suggestions and input make my life easy. Struggling for the past one week. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Entity:

```
public class SocialUser : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    
    //...
}
```

DbContextModelCreatingExtensions:

```
builder.Entity<SocialUser>(b =>
{
    b.ConfigureByConvention();
});
```

MyProjectNameDbContext:

```
builder.Entity<SocialUser>(b =>
{
    b.HasOne<AppUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
});
```

MyProjectNameMigrationsDbContext:

```
builder.Entity<SocialUser>(b =>
{
    b.HasOne<IdentityUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity:

```
public class Influencer : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public Guid AppUserId { get; set; }// Foreign key referenceing the Appuser 

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AppUserId))]
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

MyProjectNameMigrationsDbContext :

```
 builder.Entity<AppUser>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("AbpUsers");
            b.ConfigureAbpUser();
            b.ConfigureFullAuditedAggregateRoot();
            b.HasOne<IdentityUser>().WithOne().HasForeignKey<AppUser>(e => e.Id);

            b.ConfigureCustomUserProperties();
        });
```